# XCode 4: Easy way to convert Mac project to iOS?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios, macos, project

I have a huge Mac project in XCode. I want to "convert" it, or add a build target for the iphone as well. Now my problem is that my project has approximately 200 files, and there are 192 compile sources (can be seen in the build phases tab) - So adding these 192 compile sources to the iphone build target is a hard task. Is there any easy "automated" way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do this, there is certainly no option in XCode 4 to do this.

You will probably run in to a lot of errors, since UIKit is different to AppKit. There are some classes that both have, but Cocoa Touch is missing a lot and introduce some new classes.

Comment: Ok but what if the "Business Logic" of the two apps is the same? Is there a way to automate things? Is there an option to add the compile sources automatically?

Comment: Well if the "business logic", and it is not using any classes that are in AppKit only you can just use the classes in your iOS project.